# How to take advantage of Lazy Evaluation with this code?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am writing a Haskell program where I want to write to an already existing file.  The program needs to generate each string before appending it to the file.  So rather than do the entire calculation first and then append to the file, I would like the program to append each line as it is calculated.

Here is the code I attempted:

```
-- line in my do-notation of interet
-- filename = valid filename
-- records = list of record data types
appendFile fileName (map recordToString records)

recordToString :: Record -> String
recordToString r = club r ++ "," ++  mapName r ++ "," ++ nearestTown r ++ "," ++ terrain r ++ "," ++ mapGrade r ++ "," ++ gridRefOfSWCorner r ++ "," ++ gridRefOfNECorner r ++ "," ++ expectedCompletionDate r ++ "," ++ sizeSqKm r ++ ",\n"
```

I am interested in solving this problem with lazy evaluation

Comment: Isn't that already lazy? I don't see anything that would force the result of the `recordToString` calls ahead of time.

Comment: Side note: you should take a look at `intercalate` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As C. A. McCann said, this should already be lazy; however, `appendFile` will most likely open the file in block-buffered mode by default, which means that lines won't be flushed as they are created; instead, data will be written to the file a few thousand bytes at a time. To solve this problem, just roll your own function:

```
import System.IO

appendFileLines :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
appendFileLines fileName text =
  withFile fileName AppendMode $ \h -> do
    hSetBuffering h LineBuffering
    hPutStr h text
```

Then you can use `appendFileLines` instead of `appendFile`, and the file will be written to one record at a time.

What you might be thinking of, in terms of performing IO operations with lazy results, is called "lazy IO"; it's generally frowned upon, but it's not required to achieve the effect you want here. (If you know how `readFile` or `getContents` operate, for instance, that's lazy IO.)

Comment: This in and of itself is not lazy IO.  Output functions like `hPutStr` and `appendFile` block until they are finished.  However, it is lazy IO if *input* is being read lazily (e.g. with `getContents` or `readFile`).

Comment: In a sense, I would say it *is* lazy IO: the flow of IO operations and their effect on the system is being controlled by evaluation order. However, I agree it's substantially different to standard lazy IO, and my original mention of it was based on a slight misreading of the question. I'll try and clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell is lazy as a consumer, but not as a producer.  `appendFile` is lazy on input, meaning it doesn't wait until all of your content has been calculated before producing any output.  However, it is "strict" on output, in that `appendFile` will not yield the flow of execution until the entire operation has completed.

Note that if `appendFile` is using buffered or line output, it will hold off on writing anything until it has computed a chunk of output.  If buffering is disabled, it has to make a system call for every character you append, which is very slow.